# Updated python scripts on terminal - changes not reflected

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm working with some python scripts for restructuring csv data and I am running the scripts via terminal on mac osx. This was previously going fine however I am now encountering an issue where the scripts just perpetually run, even with everything commented out other than a print statement. One notable thing that is happening is I was importing Halo for a 'processing' message while the scripts ran and have removed that and yet it still shows as I attempt to run the scripts. For the sake of thoroughness here is what the terminal *should* be running (I've removed all other python code):

```
#import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
#import re

print("hello world")
```

If it has any weight, I am using atom text editor on mac osx catalina, running python 3.9.4 and using the default mac terminal. It also happens when creating a new python file. I have reset, updated, shut down and started up my mac, made the code changes seen above, and not sure what else to try. Has anyone encountered anything like this?

**Additional**
I've discovered that using any import library triggers this issue, in example requests, httpx and asyncio all create this issue just by having the import statement, clearing `__pycache__` with the imports removed fixes it, however as soon as I add the import again it is back, making it impossible to do API calls

Comment: Is there a folder '''\_\_pycache\_\_''' or similar in your folder? Delete it and start your script again. This should fix it, however I don't know where this problem is coming from.

Comment: @Las thanks for that, unfortunately the problem persists, I can try deleting it and doing a full restart to be thorough, but simply restarting terminal after did not resolve the issue

Comment: @Las weird thing I found here, if I delete the imports (not comment them out weirdly) I do get hello world without the `processing` message, especially weird since halo is completely removed